# mysql joining tables php to retrieve data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

was wondering if joining tables is the best way to retrieve data from multiple columns like i want to retrieve the fields from two columns in a table and one column from another table. 
I was wondering if this is the best way to do this.

and for retrieving the query from php i should just do a mysql_num_rows loop. correct?

Comment: explain your question better, perhaps with some code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a join is absolutely better than most alternatives; it's why joins exist. Your schema must support this with appropriate identification columns which are shared by both tables (i.e. `employees.id == paychecks.employee_id)`. You may need to create an index if you find the default indexes are not being used correctly (check the execution plan https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)

The way you iterate results in PHP depends on the library you use to fetch the data from MySQL and what you need to do with the data.